# Why does the central admin requires to run in IE with elevated privileges?

Tags: 2010, security

As described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jorman/missing-links-or-access-denied-in-central-admin-sharepoint-2010), I have to run with an elevated IE to get all actions.

What is the explanation of that? How can a web application leverage the UAC on the client (only in the same box)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is that some of these settings actually make changes on the server itself. If you are changing the logging settings for example, you have to set it up to a location where the accounts have the prifilege to write to. For this reason, you will have to set it up using run as administrator to be able to make changes to the local system.

You will also see this happen when you connect to Central admin in a hosted environment if the account used does not have local admin rights to the server.

Comment: you are explaining the symptoms, not the cause. What I don't understand, is how can a Web Application (not SP especially) can use the UAC. In my understanding, the things are done by the process that hosts the web application (in this case, the SP admin process). The security of the application checks the user rights based on its login and a table of authorizations. Where does the UAC on the computer applies in this chain ?

Comment: The configuration changes that you make through CA are all stored in a database. Where you have to run as administrator (where UAC is in effect) is when it actually has to make a change on the local machine as well.